# How to load multiple image of specified size?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, image-loading

I want to load multiple image(list view or gridview) of specified size (i need to change  height and width of image at run time) .Can anyone suggest me for any library which support this functionality ?

```
imageloader.loadimage(imageview,"imageurl",height,width);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out UniversalImageLoader. I think this is the best library for loading images. In its loading listener you can resize the loaded image before display it.

Answer (score 1):

Try by this one : and check this for refrence https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(120, 80); // result Bitmap will be fit to this size
 imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, targetSize, displayOptions, new     SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
}
 });
```